# How to upgrade DolphinDB in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, upgrade, pid, dolphindb

I created a container environment with the Docker Image provided by DolphinDB and did some testing. Now I want to upgrade DolphinDB without exiting the container.

I need to kill the DolphinDB process before upgrading. But now I encountered a problem:  the PID of DolphinDB in my container is 1, which means DolphinDB will start automatically when the container is started, and that the container will stop when closing DolphinDB. So I can’t follow the normal upgrade process. How can I do this?

Comment: If you're using the official images, then the Docker procedure is to kill the running container and start up a new one with the updated software. One of the characteristics of containers is that they're ephemeral. I.e. they're intended to be killed and restarted. You should not update software in a running container.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the problem may be that the entryPoint command for the container initiates the dolphindb process. So, you can just override entryPoint command.

For example:

```
docker run -itd --name=ddb-non-startup -p 8848:8848  --ulimit core=-1  --entrypoint "sh" dolphindb/dolphindb:v2.00.8
```

Change the entryPoint command as specified in thescript above, so that the DolphinDB process will not start automatically when the container is started. After that, you can just run the `upgrade.sh` script in the clusterDemo directory to upgrade your database.